# How to routerLinkActive non anchor link

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have two links on my application component

```
<a routerLink="/dashboard" routerLinkActive="active">Dashboard</a>    --> app/dashboard
<a routerLink="/heroes" routerLinkActive="active">Heroes</a>          --> app/heroes
```

After I click a hero I go into "hero details" screen, but the "Heroes" link is not active.

I'd like to highlight "heroes" anchor when I`m on app/detail/:id

```
path: 'detail/:id'
```

That's my full routes const:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/dashboard',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'detail/:id',
    component: HeroDetailComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'dashboard',
    component: DashboardComponent
  },
  {
      path: 'heroes',
      component: HeroesComponent
  }
];
```

your kind assistance appreciated

Comment: Only thing I can think of is to make the `detail/:id` route a child route of the `heroes` route.  I don't think there is a way to tell angular to show a route as active even if you aren't on that route.

Comment: Something like: `{path: 'heroes',children: [{path: "", component: HeroesComponent}, {path: "detail/:id", component: HeroDetailComponent}]}`

Comment: I get a

_core.umd.js:3462 EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes: 'detail/11'_


Why do I need to define an empty path if there is already a heroes path defined above?
The heroes is not a child of the heroes path...

Comment: using this child method, you move the component out of the original path declaration and into the child routes, the empty path just means when you hit `/heroes` it'll load that component, but when you hit `/heroes/detail/:id` you'll go to the other component. The error you got is because you need to update the link you were using to go to the `detail` route to go to `/heroes/detail`

Comment: SOLVED:

Had to manipulate my navigate function on the router.

Added `'/heroes'` before `'/detail/` and it worked.

`this.router.navigate(['/heroes/detail', this.selectedHero.id]);`

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only method I know of to keep the routerLinkActive enabled on a route is to use child routes.  Updating the routes as such:

```
{path: 'heroes',children: [
    {path: "", component: HeroesComponent},
    {path: "detail/:id", component: HeroDetailComponent}
]}
```

will let you navigate to `/heroes` and `/heroes/detail/:id` and leave `/heroes` as the active route

Further, there are options you can add to the route if you do NOT want this behavior on the parent route, you can find those [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html)